# power point printing problem using C#

Tags: c#, printing, powerpoint

I'm using the COM objects from Office 2007 to handle and print ms-office files. I don't have any problems with word and excel documents, but i just can't print Power Point docs.

the code bellow just opens the file send a job to the printer but nothing gets printed

what am i doing wrong? =(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Main
{
    class PrintPPoint
    {
        public static void PrintPPointDocument(string filename, int copies, string range)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation work = null;            
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations presprint = app.Presentations;
            //app.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            work = presprint.Open(filename, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
            work.PrintOptions.PrintInBackground = 0;
            work.PrintOptions.ActivePrinter = app.ActivePrinter;
            if (range.Equals("0"))            
            {                
                work.PrintOut(0, 1, app.ActivePrinter, copies, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);                
            }
            else
            {
                string[] toprintsheet = range.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                foreach (string aux in toprintsheet)
                {
                    work.PrintOptions.PrintInBackground = 0;
                    work.PrintOptions.ActivePrinter = app.ActivePrinter;
                    if (aux.Contains("-"))
                    {
                        int from = 0, to = 0;
                        string[] SplitRange = aux.Split(new char[] { '-' });
                        from = Convert.ToInt16(SplitRange[0]);
                        to = Convert.ToInt16(SplitRange[1]);                        
                        work.PrintOut(from, to, app.ActivePrinter, 1, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        work.PrintOut(Convert.ToInt16(aux), Convert.ToInt16(aux), app.ActivePrinter, copies, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                    }

                }
            }
            work.Close();
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to set

```
PrintOptions.PrintInBackground = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
```

That lets the jobs complete.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you but I bet you can easily find out yourself...

I assume that this is an application that interacts with the desktop and not some background service.

I would step through the code slowly and see if it works.. (for both app.visible = true and not.)  If it works, it may be a race between ppoint printing functionality and ppoint closing the document/quiting.  (Even though you've turned off background printing) and you have check for that...

Good luck